# Object of type Series is not JSON serializable

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, postgresql, psycopg2

i have dataset and i want to upload this data to PostgreSQL database
,this is sample of data
this is pandas dataframe

```
         key                                   changes
        LDELM27360          {'Access Control List': ['AUTO_CREATED', 'MANUAL_CREATED']}
        LDELE47148          {'Access Control List': ['AUTO_CREATED', 'MANUAL_CREATED']}
        LDELW24536          {'Access Control List': ['AUTO_CREATED', 'MANUAL_CREATED']}
        LDELE34286          {'Access Control List': ['AUTO_CREATED', 'MANUAL_CREATED']}
```

when i upload changes columns it gives error can't upload dict which can't serializable  after searching on stack overflow they recommended to use

```
json.dumps()
```

but gives error

```
Object of type Series is not JSON serializable
```

is there another way to upload this data ?

Comment: What is the result of `print(type(df.loc[0, 'changes']))`?

Comment: 'pandas.core.series.Series'>